# Kubernetes : load balancing on a not-REST container

Tags: kubernetes, session, scale

I'm new to kubernetes. I have learned about **kubectl scale** to spawn replicas, but it doesn't work well because my containers (shiny app) keep a session-specific context. Each session needs to keep being routed to the same container.

Hence, I'd like to get a simple way to :

- Keep a routing cache to route the same IP always to the same pod (with a timeout obviously) to avoid any context problem
- If possible, I'd like an adaptive rule somewhat like "number_of_replicas = 2 + ceiling(nb_users/10)" (prespawn a pool of two, and adapt)

Is there a simple way of doing that ?

Comment: This is extremely common in the non container world and is known as affinity or sticky sessions.  https://saturncloud.io/blog/how-to-use-session-affinity-on-requests-to-kubernetes-service-a-guide/ https://itnext.io/sticky-sessions-and-canary-releases-in-kubernetes-8c45de2b0a2e https://pauldally.medium.com/session-affinity-and-kubernetes-proceed-with-caution-8e66fd5deb05

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Session affinity](https://itnext.io/sticky-sessions-and-canary-releases-in-kubernetes-8c45de2b0a2e)** or commonly called as **sticky sessions** will help you in routing the subsequent requests of a session to the same pod. Using any kubernetes ingress controller you can achieve this functionality, however if you are trying to use a simple solution there are certain limitations that you need to take care of, in [this](https://pauldally.medium.com/session-affinity-and-kubernetes-proceed-with-caution-8e66fd5deb05) article written by Paul Dally, he has explained how to use session affinity for routing the traffic, it’s limitations and an outline on how to overcome this issue.

Note: The blog is written by **Daniele Polencic**, (the hyperlink provided for session affinity) also details how to configure session affinity and it’s limitations.

Comment: Thank you. I'm more from the data world hence I wouldn't know the right word. Thanks, I'll check that.